# How can I ensure that my Quilt data package displays relevant information by default in the catalog UI view?

Tags: python, json, quiltdata

When viewing a [Quilt data package](https://quiltdata.com/) in the catalog view, how do I ensure that the relevant information and data to my users bubbles up from N-depth of folders/files to the data package landing view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I originally wrote this answer when I was working at Quilt Data]*

Create a file called `quilt_summarize.json` [[Reference]](https://docs.quiltdata.com/catalog/visualizationdashboards#quilt_summarize.json) which is a configuration file that renders one or more data-package elements in both Bucket view and Packages view. The contents of `quilt_summarize.json` are a JSON array of files that you wish to preview in the catalog, from any depth in your data package. Each file may be represented as a string or, if you wish to provide more configuration, as an object. You can preview all sorts of different files out-of-the-box including JSON, CSV, TXT, MD, XLS, XLSX, PARQUET, TSV, visualization libraries (including Vega, Altair, eCharts, and Voila), and iPython notebooks.

Here's the syntax:

```json
// quilt_summarize.json
[
  "file1.json",
  "root_folder/second_level/third_level/file2.csv",
  "notebooks/file3.ipynb"
]
```

You can also define multi-column outputs:

```json
[
  "file1.json",
  [{
    "path": "file2.csv",
    "width": "200px"
  }, {
    "path": "file3.ipynb",
    "title": "Scientific notebook",
    "description": "[See docs](https://docs.com)"
  }]
]
```

which will render the file `file1.json` first (and span the whole width of the screen), then the viewport will be split into N columns (based on N-length of the JSON array) in the widths defined in the attributes.